# django models objects filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model 'Test' ,in which i have 2 foreignkey

## models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id =models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
    name=models.ForeignKey(model2)
    login=models.ForeignKey(model1)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200)



class model1(models.Model):
   id=models.CharField(primary_key=True)
   .
   .

   is_active=models.IntergerField()


 class model2(model.Model):
    id=models.ForeignKey(model1)
     .

     .
     status=model.CharField(max_length=200)
```

When i add object in model 'Test' , if i select certain login then only the objects related to that objects(model2) should be shown in field 'name'.How can i achieve this.THis will be runtime as if i change the login field value the objects in name should also change.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the save method of class *Test*.
So you could set *name* to everithing you want based on login.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    .
    .
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.name = self.login.model_set()[0] # or what ever you want
        super(Test, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Comment: probably you should change your model definition. Why you need name=models.ForeignKey(model2)? isn't it a redundant information?

Comment: i need a runtime change in name value.I think i need to do it with jquery only.There is no other way for this.First i will only show the login field and when user select the login field i will do ajax call and populate the name field accoriding to it only.